# How to remove a CSS class from a Wicket component?

Tags: java, css, wicket

It's pretty straightforward to dynamically **add** a CSS class to a component in Java code using an [AttributeAppender](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/behavior/AttributeAppender.html):

```
component.add(new AttributeAppender("class", true, new Model<String>("foo"), " "));
```

Or, if you've extracted the above into an appropriate utility method or class, simply something like:

```
component.add(WicketUtils.cssClassAppender("foo"));
```

**But how can I remove a CSS class?**

You can easily remove *all* CSS classes by clearing the class attribute altogether:

```
component.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("class", ""));
```

...but that is not acceptable if the component has other CSS classes that you do *not* wish to remove.

Wicket 1.4 (but feel free to post advice specific to later versions too).

Comment: Not useful, eh - care to elaborate, downvoter? IMHO it's useful (for myself and others) to document non-immediately-obvious aspects of Wicket here on SO.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's one way I came up with:

```
public class CssClassRemover extends AttributeModifier {
    public CssClassRemover(String cssClass) {
        super("class", false, new Model<String>(cssClass));
    }

    @Override
    protected String newValue(String currentValue, String valueToRemove) {
        // NB: naive approach; breaks with e.g. "foo foo-bar" & "foo"
        return currentValue.replaceAll(valueToRemove, "");
    }
}
```

The code that uses the above helper would then be:

```
component.add(new CssClassRemover("foo"))
```

(Of course you can also just create anonymous AttributeModifier subclasses as needed, but putting the logic in a separate utility class or method cleans it up a lot.)

**Edit**: An improved version of `newValue()` that handles corner cases better (see comment by biziclop). NB: uses [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). (You're welcome to post simpler (regex?) versions.)

```
@Override
protected String newValue(String currentValue, String valueToRemove) {
    if (currentValue == null) return "";

    Set<String> classes = Sets.newHashSet(Splitter.on(" ").split(currentValue));
    classes.remove(valueToRemove);
    return Joiner.on(" ").join(classes); 
}
```

Comment: **Feel free to post better / simpler ways to do this.** Specifically if I overlooked something like this that comes with Wicket built-in...

Comment: Depending on the use case it could also be suitable to use an `AttributeModifier` and decide which classes to use in an `IModel`.

Comment: You should add whitespace (and string start/end) matching to the beginning and the end of `valueToRemove`, just consider the case where `class="foo foo-bar"` Even better if you use `currentValue.split( "\\s+" )` to obtain all the individual classes and then re-append them without the one you want to remove. For a bonus point, you can also do the same to `valueToRemove` to be able to remove several classes with a single `CssClassRemover`.

Comment: @biziclop: Good call! I'm not a big fan of regex minutiae, so I quickly coded a Guava version that *should* be pretty robust. If anyone doesn't like it, competing implementations are welcome. :-)

Comment: Well, if you're using Guava anyway, it's easy. :)

Answer (score 3):

Building on [Jonik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10135837/168939), the following adds negative lookahead to ignore occurrences in the middle of a different style class (and is case insensitive).

```
public class StyleClassRemover extends AttributeModifier {

    public StyleClassRemover(final String cssClass) {
        super("class", false, Model.of(cssClass));
    }

    @Override
    protected String newValue(final String currentValue, final String valueToRemove) {
        if (currentValue == null) {
            return "";
        }

        final String patternString = "(^|\\s+)" + Pattern.quote(valueToRemove) + "(?!\\S)";
        return Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(currentValue).replaceAll("");
    }
}
```

Tested input:
http://fiddle.re/ah0ca6

Answer (score 0):

Wicket 1.5+ has org.apache.wicket.AttributeModifier#remove()

Comment: Hmm, looking at the javadoc ("Creates a attribute modifier that removes an attribute with the specified name"), it doesn't seem to do what I want... Sounds like it would remove the "class" attribute entirely, just like the SimpleAttributeModifier example in the question.